# asp.net mvc HTML5 date input type

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, datepicker

I am working an asp.net mvc in visual studio 2013 and one of the fields is a date input but when clicking in the field and having focus in the field the automatic HTML5 datepicker does not come up. If I put the field in manually it comes up but then it doesn't map to that particular field. In the data annotations I have included [DataType(DataType.Date)] but this doesn't bring up the HTML5 date picker. How do I achieve this in asp.net below is the code for the field in particular

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CustomerJoinDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CustomerJoinDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CustomerJoinDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What about adding the attribute type="date" into the htmlattributes brackets?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions guys, what i did was put the type="date" in the html attributes in the "EditorFor" line and that did the trick

Comment: I put in the example in my answer if you want to use the editorfor instead of textboxfor

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Can't remember exactly when this was added but in older versions of ASP.NET MVC you could either modify the default editor template to add support for it or use `TextBoxFor` which allows you to specify any custom attributes:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.CustomerJoinDate, new { 
    @class = "form-control", 
    type = "date" 
})
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want your DateTime model properties to use the same template without having to repeat the same Razor code over and over, define a partial view called `DateTime.cshtml` (or `DateTime.vbhtml`) in your `Shared/EditorTemplates` folder, with content similar to:

```
@model DateTime

@Html.TextBoxFor(
    m => m, 
    "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", 
    new { @class = "form-control date", type = "date" })
```

Then replace your Razor bindings with:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.CustomerJoinDate)
```

and so on, for each date field which should use this template.

This uses an [overload of TextBoxFor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.textboxfor%28v=vs.118%29.aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions.TextBoxFor%60%602%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper%7B%60%600%7D,System.Linq.Expressions.Expression%7BSystem.Func%7B%60%600,%60%601%7D%7D,System.String,System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary%7BSystem.String,System.Object%7D%29) that allows you to specify a [format string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) for the input, which is helpful for "masking" the time portion of the DateTime value (assuming you only want to enter a date).

Since [not every browser supports a native datepicker](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime), you could use the `date` class in this example to apply a polyfill as necessary (or simply use `type=date` as your selector).

Answer (score 2):

MVC 5.1 now supports using html attributes directly like so.  You should be able to put date into the type attibute.

```
<div class="form-group">
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.CustomerJoinDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
<div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CustomerJoinDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", type = "date" } })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CustomerJoinDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

See Darin's answer regarding `input type="date"` via `TextBoxFor`

> *"...but when clicking in the field and having focus in the field the automatic HTML5 datepicker  does not come up"*

At the base level, [not all browsers have "native" implementation of a "datepicker"](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime), so you'll likely need to implement a plugin to work across browsers (e.g. [bootstrap datepicker](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Bootstrap.Datepicker) and such)

Example:

```html
<p>
  See if you get a datepicker in Firefox (as of v40.0.2):
  <br />
  <input type="date" name="foo" />
</p>
```

Hth...